# Angular Fire 2 : getting last element in FirebaseListObservable list.

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular2-forms, angularfire2

I have a FirebaseListObservable List which I am getting from the firebase. My Object looks something like this :

```
{
  "0" : {
    "completed" : false,
    "description" : "Grab the grocerry",
    "id" : 25,
    "status" : true,
    "title" : "Grocerry"
  },
  "1" : {
    "completed" : false,
    "description" : "some task",
    "id" : 26,
    "status" : true,
    "title" : "Complete this"
  }
}
```

Here I want to update the Ids sequentially, One way of  FirebaseListObservable using forEach. But that will be too expensive as the list grows. So my question is that, 
1) How can I find some element with the Ids. 
2) How to get the last index of Ids in order to update the IDs sequentially.

My Code :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { todo } from  '../shared/todo';
import {AngularFireDatabaseModule,AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable} from 'angularfire2/database';
import {AngularFireAuthModule, AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-task',
  templateUrl: './add-task.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-task.component.css']
})
export class AddTaskComponent {
    newTask :todo = new todo();
    finalObject : todo = new todo();
    active: boolean = true;
    todos: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
    constructor(afAuth: AngularFireAuth, db: AngularFireDatabase) {
     // this.user = afAuth.authState;
      this.todos = db.list('todos');
    }
    onSubmit() {
        console.log(this.newTask);
        console.log(this.todos);
        this.finalObject = {
            'id' : 29,
            'title' : this.newTask.title,
            'description' :this.newTask.description,
            'status':true,
            'completed' :false
        };
        //this.todos.push(this.newTask);

        this.newTask = new todo();
        /* To reset the form*/
            this.active=false;
            setTimeout ( ()=> this.active=true,0);
        /* To reset the form*/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

this.todos = db.list('todos').do(data => this.length = data.length);
```

And when you want to update the last item simply do:

```
db.list('todos').update(this.length - 1, newData);
```

Comment: .do() method doesn't work for me as it is not supported by FirebaseListObservable list. Can you suggest some other way,

Comment: It is if you import it from rxjs.